# make dart code runs at device reboot flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I searched everywhere but could not find a proper solution, I am looking for a way to make some code runs when the device restarts, check the internet for new notifications,for example.
I find the 'notifier' https://pub.dev/packages/notifier#-readme-tab- package that might be useful but I am not sure of that

Comment: try https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager for example (check `RebootBroadcastReceiver` in `Getting Started` section)?

Comment: is this valid for ios devices @pskink

Comment: i have no idea (probably not): this is what i found in 30 seconds at https://pub.dev/

Comment: sure, your welcome